# Why would SQL Server stop excluding partitions appropriately?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partitioning, execution-plan, statistics

I have a Fact Table that will run with an appropriate plan during our morning processing. Occasionally, later in the day, if I go to query it, it will have a really strange plan.

When querying a table partitioned on date, you usually see a seek predicate like so:

[image: goodquery]

But for some reason, it turns into this:

[image]

Yes, I'm aware that there are two different tables shown above. I pulled the good example from a similarly configured table, and it appropriately displays the seek predicate I would expect.

Both of these are Clustered Index Seek operators. Updating stats doesn't seem to help, but some part of [Ola's maintenance scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/) seem to fix it each morning.

Has anybody seen this before? Any tips on how to restore the good plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second execution plan, the seek predicate has a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` function in it. This means the wrong data type was input and SQL Server has to convert the data type to something else. In this case, it was expecting a `DATE` data type and something other than `DATE` was passed in... most likely a `(VAR)CHAR` or `N(VAR)CHAR` value. The fix would be to either explicitly cast/convert the value before submitting the query or fix the code to use the proper data type.

Here are some further resources on the matter:

- [Implicit_Conversions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2008/06/05/implicit-conversions/)
- [Conversion Matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_9)
- [Performance Issues with Convert_Implicit](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1734/convert-implicit-and-the-related-performance-issues-with-sql-server/)

Comment: I understand what you are saying - but I'm not sure how to fix it. We query this table all the time using `where SaleDate = '8/1/2016'` and this doesn't happen. This is the same way I queried the good plan pictured above. I added an explicit cast and convert, with no luck.

Comment: Ok, scratch that - an explicit convert with option (recompile) seems to have done the trick. I still find this behavior strange. Thank you for your help.